# How to get the query result for "not in between these two dates"

Tags: php, mysql

How to get the query result for "not in between these two dates"

Query1:

```
SELECT *
FROM   log
WHERE  employee_id = 2
AND    date BETWEEN '2013-12-01' and '2013-12-08'
```

When I run the query I get the result

```
2013-12-1
2013-12-5
```

But how to get the result "all dates other than the above two".
Or, how do I write the query to get the result below?

```
2013-12-2
2013-12-3
2013-12-4
2013-12-6
2013-12-7
2013-12-8
```

Comment: That doesn't make sense, that query would return EVERY row, not just those 2 dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you want all the dates when there was no logged activity by the specified user.
Following solution is based on another answer: [SHOW ALL Dates data between two dates; if no row exists for particular date then show zero in all columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12890967/show-all-dates-data-between-two-dates-if-no-row-exists-for-particular-date-then)

```
    ;with d(date) as (
      select CAST('20131201' AS datetime)
      union all
      select date+1
      from d
      where date < CAST('20131208' AS datetime)
      )
    select d.date CDate
    from d
    left join [Log] l
           on l.[Date] = d.date AND l.employee_id=2
    WHERE l.employee_id IS NULL
    order by d.date
    OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Sorry, this is for SQL Server not MySQL, I did not see the MySQL tag... Anyway I think this is what you expect and there will be similar solution for MySQL.

EDIT

There seems to be no WITH clause in MySQL :-(. If you are sure you have every day some other log record (other users actions, system events etc.), then the following command could work for you:

```
SELECT DISTINCT date FROM log l1 
  WHERE l1.date BETWEEN '2013-12-01' and '2013-12-08' 
  AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM log l2 WHERE 
                  l2.date = l1.date AND  l2.employee_id=2)
```

I did not test it, because I have presently no MySQL installed.

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
 select * 
   from log 
  WHERE employee_id =2 
    AND NOT date between '2013-12-01' and '2013-12-08'
```

You could also do

```
 AND ( date < '2013-12-01'  OR date > '2013-12-08')
```

But, if your `date` column has timestamps that aren't midnight in it, you need to think harder about ranges. You'll need

```
AND ( date < '2013-12-01' AND date >= ('2013-12-08' + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

to get timesamps in the appropriate date range.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT '2013-12-2'
UNION
SELECT '2013-12-3'
etc
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a SQL standard operator, `NOT BETWEEN` which you can use:

```
select * 
from log 
WHERE employee_id = 2 and
      date not between '2013-12-01' and '2013-12-08';
```

This should be equivalent to:

```
select * 
from log 
WHERE employee_id = 2 and
      not (date between '2013-12-01' and '2013-12-08');
```

However, the latter is logically two operations (calculate the "date between" part and then negate the result).  The first is one operation.

By the way, be very careful if the `date` is really stored as a `datetime` type.  The time component can throw off equality operations and make the `between return unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

> "select * from log WHERE employee_id =2 AND  date between '2013-12-01' and '2013-12-08'"

the preceding query returns '2013-10-1' and '2013-12-5', and you are looking for

```
2013-12-2
2013-12-3
2013-12-4
2013-12-6
2013-12-7
2013-12-8
```

But your question is `how to get the query result not in between the date`. this makes sense?

Anyway According to your expected results. I think you are looking for

```
select * from log WHERE employee_id =2 AND  date != '2013-12-01' and date != '2013-12-08'
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM another_tab WHERE date NOT IN (
    select date from log WHERE employee_id =2 AND  date BETWEEN '2013-12-01' and  '2013-12-08'
)
```