# SQL - SHOW ALL DATES between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have following data saved as dates in my `[OccuredAtUtc]`  that look like this:

-- *Spoiler ALERT: "2017-04-26" and "2017-04-29" are missing.*

> Original dates in `[OccuredAtUtc]`:

```
2017-04-24 12:16:58.5080000
2017-04-24 18:11:53.3090000
2017-04-25 18:34:18.3090000
2017-04-27 20:42:28.8570000
2017-04-28 21:10:36.7070000
2016-04-28 10:37:57.5970000
2016-04-30 10:38:55.7010000
2016-04-30 10:48:19.0390000
2016-04-31 10:48:19.2990000
.
.
.
```

And I have this code that returns correctly data from two intervals (previous week).

```
SELECT 
        [MessageType].[Name] AS [Channel],
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), [OccuredAtUtc], 106) AS [Time],
        COUNT(*) AS [Count]
FROM @table1
        INNER JOIN @table2 ON ... = ...
WHERE ( [OccuredAtUtc] > '2017-04-24'
        AND [OccuredAtUtc] < '2017-04-30' )
GROUP BY (CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), [OccuredAtUtc], 106)),
         [MessageType].[Name]
ORDER BY [Time] ASC
```

But **the output won't show a row of the "26 Apr 2017" and "29 Apr 2017"** because there are not records on these days in my DB.

**OLD OUTPUT :**  with missing 26th & 29th Apr.

```
[Channel]       [Time]          [Count]
------------------------------------
FTP           24 Apr 2017         7
HTTP          24 Apr 2017         9
FTP           25 Apr 2017         6
HTTP          25 Apr 2017         2
------MISSING 26 Apr--------
FTP           27 Apr 2017         56
HTTP          27 Apr 2017         12
FTP           28 Apr 2017         5
------MISSING 29 Apr--------
HTTP          28 Apr 2017         17
FTP           30 Apr 2017         156
HTTP          30 Apr 2017         19
```

I would like to **show rows WITH THE MISSING DATE even if there was not an incident** saved on this day...

So the new OUTPUT should look like this.

**WANTED OUTPUT :**

```
[Channel]       [Time]          [Count]
------------------------------------
FTP             24 Apr 2017        7
HTTP            24 Apr 2017        9
FTP             25 Apr 2017        6
HTTP            25 Apr 2017        2
0               26 Apr 2017        0  -- here we go
FTP             27 Apr 2017        56
HTTP            27 Apr 2017        12
FTP             28 Apr 2017        5
HTTP            28 Apr 2017        17
0               29 Apr 2017        0  -- here we go
FTP             30 Apr 2017        156
HTTP            30 Apr 2017        19
```

I know there are answered question like mine and I was trying to remake my code but I failed.

( [SHOW ALL Dates data between two dates; if no row exists for particular date then show zero in all columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12890967/show-all-dates-data-between-two-dates-if-no-row-exists-for-particular-date-then) )

( [How to generate all dates between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32982372/how-to-generate-all-dates-between-two-dates) )

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to @DhruvJoshi's answer but using a recursive CTE to generate the dates instead:

```
DECLARE @MinDate DATE = '20170424',
        @MaxDate DATE = '20170430';

WITH allDates AS
(
    SELECT @MinDate AS dates

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, ad.[dates] )
    FROM allDates AS ad
    WHERE ad.[dates] < @MaxDate
)

SELECT 
        ISNULL([MessageType].[Name],0) AS [Channel],
        dates AS [Time],
        COUNT([MessageType].[Name]) AS [Count]
FROM 
(
   SELECT dates
   FROM allDates
) AS T
LEFT JOIN 
@table1 ON T.dates=CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), @table1.[OccuredAtUtc], 106)
        LEFT JOIN @table2 ON ... = ...
GROUP BY dates,
         [MessageType].[Name]
ORDER BY [Time] ASC
```

Comment: Thank you Alex, you solved my problem ! <3
There is a little mystake ur code, there should be .[dates] instead of .Time.
Here is how my final solution looks like : https://ibb.co/nanfkk
Thanks again, you saved me.

Comment: Thanks. I changed the column from Time to dates but forgot to update one of them! I had a suggested edit so have approved that :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like a Tally table to generate all dates between certain time interval.

```
SELECT 
        ISNULL([MessageType].[Name],0) AS [Channel],
        dates AS [Time],
        COUNT([MessageType].[Name]) AS [Count]
FROM 
(
   SELECT 
      TOP (DATEDIFF(d,'2017-04-24','2017-04-30')+1) 
       DATEADD(d,ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY (SELECT 1))-1,'2017-04-24') dates
    FROM sys.objects a CROSS JOIN sys.objects b 
)T
LEFT JOIN 
@table1 ON T.dates=CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), @table1.[OccuredAtUtc], 106)
        LEFT JOIN @table2 ON ... = ...
AND ( [OccuredAtUtc] > '2017-04-24'
        AND [OccuredAtUtc] < '2017-04-30' )
GROUP BY dates,
         [MessageType].[Name]
ORDER BY [Time] ASC
```

For more explanation on Tally tables please read **[this article](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/)**

Comment: I don't know Joshi... First of all thank you for the tip with Tally tables, I have never heard about something like that.
Anyway, I tried this code and it **still doesnt show the missing dates** and the output in column looks like "2017-04-18 00:00:00.000" instead of this "24 Apr 2017"

Comment: Isn't there some "elegant solution" how to solve my problem? All I need is to show the missing dates from the interval too... :/

Comment: For `the output in column looks like "2017-04-18 00:00:00.000" instead of this "24 Apr 2017"` you can always format correctly.

Comment: For `still doesnt show the missing dates `, that was due to WHERE criteria. I've corrected my answer. please try now

Comment: Still doesnt show the missing date :(
You can see it here: https://ibb.co/chHUt5
It is example for an interval 16 Apr - 23 Apr (two weeks ago), where there is not record on 17 Apr ... And so 17 Apr is not displayed in the output neither.   -- for a week ago It behaves the same way
What do you think Joshi? PS: It is not problem with DB

Comment: @RadimŠafrán OK I saw what is the problem. It's the INNER JOIN. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table ( i int identity , b bit, d as dateadd (dd, i - 1, 0 ))

insert into @t (b)
VALUES (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)

insert into @t (b)
select 0
from @t t1
cross apply ( select b from @t) as t2
cross apply ( select b from @t) as t3
cross apply ( select b from @t) as t4
cross apply ( select b from @t) as t5

select t.d, isnull(y.channel,0), count(y.[date])
from @t t
    left join yourtable y on y.[date] = t.d
where d between getdate() - 30 and getdate()
group by t.d, isnull(y.channel,0)
```