# Show every week of the Year even if there is no data

Tags: t-sql

I have query that pulls data by week and groups it together. But i does not display weeks that doesn't have any data. I want show all weeks even if they don't have data as null maybe

Here is the query if someone can help me with this it will awesome

```
SELECT 
    DATEADD (week, datediff(week, 0, StartDate), -1) as 'WeekOf'
   ,DATEADD (week, datediff(week, 0, StartDate), +5) as 'to'
   ,DATEPART(wk, StartDate) as 'WeekNumber'

FROM [DESOutage].[dbo].[OPSInterruption]

Where  StartDate > '2020-01-01' and EndDate <'2020-02-01' 

Group by DATEADD (week, datediff(week, 0, StartDate), -1),DATEPART(wk, StartDate),DATEADD (week, datediff(week, 0, StartDate), +5)
```

***************Output***************
As you could see week  2 and 4 is missing out since there is no data being returned. I would still like to see week 2 and 4 in the output with maybe 0 as result.

WeekOf                      to                  WeekNumber
2019-12-29 00:00:00.000 2020-01-04 00:00:00.000 1
2020-01-12 00:00:00.000 2020-01-18 00:00:00.000 3
2020-01-26 00:00:00.000 2020-02-01 00:00:00.000 5

Comment: You also probably want `>=` for the `StartDate` comparison.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SHOW ALL Dates data between two dates; if no row exists for particular date then show zero in all columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12890967/show-all-dates-data-between-two-dates-if-no-row-exists-for-particular-date-then)

Comment: This has been asked and answered over and over again here (and elsewhere). The suggested link shows a few ways, but the short answer is that you'll need to generate a list of dates to join from, either from a calendar table, a numbers table, or a CTE or subquery that generates one of the above on an ad hoc basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need a calendar table. Here is a quick way of generating one, with an untested implementation of your code. I am assuming that the StartDate may contain a time component thus the need to coalesce the dates.

```
DECLARE @StartYear DATETIME = '20200101'
DECLARE @days      INT      = 366

;WITH
  E1(N) AS (
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
  ),                                   -- 1*10^1 or 10 rows
  E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), -- 1*10^2 or 100 rows
  E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), -- 1*10^4 or 10,000 rows
  E8(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E4 a, E4 b), -- 1*10^8 or 100,000,000 rows
  Tally(N) AS (SELECT TOP (@Days) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E8),
  Calendar AS (
    SELECT  StartOfDay = DATEADD(dd,N-1,@StartYear),
            EndOfDay   = DATEADD(second, -1, DATEADD(dd,N  ,@StartYear))
    FROM Tally)

SELECT  DATEADD (week, datediff(week, 0, COALESCE(x.StartDate, c.StartOfDay) ), -1) as 'WeekOf'
      , DATEADD (week, datediff(week, 0, COALESCE(x.StartDate, c.StartOfDay)), +5) as 'to'
      , DATEPART(wk, COALESCE(x.StartDate, c.StartOfDay)) as 'WeekNumber'
FROM    Calendar c
        INNER JOIN [DESOutage].[dbo].[OPSInterruption] x
                ON x.StartDate > c.StartOfDay AND x.StartDate <= c.EndOfDay
WHERE   c.StartOfDay > '2020-01-01' AND c.StartOfDay <'2020-02-01' 
GROUP BY DATEADD (week, datediff(week, 0, COALESCE(x.StartDate, c.StartOfDay)), -1),
         DATEPART(wk, COALESCE(x.StartDate, c.StartOfDay)),
         DATEADD (week, datediff(week, 0, COALESCE(x.StartDate, c.StartOfDay)), +5)
```