# Get data between two dates in laravel, if data does not exist it should return 0 as count

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Here I have a situation to solve in laravel query, where I need to get the data between specific date from a table and return the data, But I need to return all the data including non-exist dates as well.

Here is my table structure--

```
id | date        | user_id
1    2022-08-02      1
2    2022-08-02      2
3    2022-08-01      2
```

Now if I get the data from database between 25-07-2022 to 02-08-2022, then the result set should be ---

```
  date      |   user_count
2022-08-02          2
2022-08-01          1
2022-07-31          0
2022-07-30          0
2022-07-29          0
2022-07-28          0
2022-07-27          0
2022-07-26          0
2022-07-25          0
```

this is the result how I need to get in the query. Please let me know which query I should write to fetch the data like above output.
I have written the normal mysql query and laravel query, but not able to find the query solution for above output.. please suggest
Thanks in advance

Comment: How is your current query looking alike?

Comment: You would need a table of dates to LEFT JOIN and group on, even if it is a temporary table. Otherwise a `DatePeriod` of dates within the desired period can be used to iterate over and fill in the missing dates from the query results as `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrote something fast, should print the wanted result

```
  $period = CarbonPeriod::create('2018-06-14', '2018-06-20');
    foreach ($period as $date)
    {
       $arr[] = DB::table('table_name')->selectRaw('date, count(user_id)')->where('date', $date)->get()->toArray();
    }
    dd($arr);
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. can we not write any single query for it?

Comment: You can, have to probably check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12890967/show-all-dates-data-between-two-dates-if-no-row-exists-for-particular-date-then

Comment: If there is more dates GAP like 6 months then how we can manage that one?

Comment: You just need to define the dates in that case, either with sql or Carbon @DeveloperNetset

Comment: Personally, I would inverse the operation to fill in the missing dates from the array of database results. 1) Create date period for desired date-range. 2) Query min/max of the date period from database table. 3) Iterate over each date within the date period with a conditional to check db query result dataset for the date and add a record to the array for the missing date and 0 if is not found within the db dataset.

Comment: @WillB. Yes this could be a better solution as well, less queries is better

Answer (score 0):

```
->whereBetween('date',[ 2022-07-25, 2022-08-02])
```

I think The code above will work

Comment: this is so wrong.

Comment: This will just return the data with the dates which exists in the database, I just need the dates as well, which does not exists in the db and returns 0 in that date.